# How do I access embedded json objects in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, twitter, pandas

**TL;DR If loaded fields in a Pandas DataFrame contain JSON documents themselves, how can they be worked with in a Pandas like fashion?**

Currently I'm directly dumping json/dictionary results from a Twitter library ([twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython)) into a Mongo collection (called users here).

```
from twython import Twython
from pymongo import MongoClient

tw = Twython(...<auth>...)

# Using mongo as object storage 
client = MongoClient()
db = client.twitter
user_coll = db.users

user_batch = ... # collection of user ids
user_dict_batch = tw.lookup_user(user_id=user_batch)

for user_dict in user_dict_batch:
    if(user_coll.find_one({"id":user_dict['id']}) == None):
        user_coll.insert(user_dict)
```

After populating this database I read the documents into Pandas:

```
# Pull straight from mongo to pandas
cursor = user_coll.find()
df = pandas.DataFrame(list(cursor))
```

Which works like magic:

[image: Pandas is magic]

I'd like to be able to mangle the 'status' field Pandas style (directly accessing attributes). Is there a way?

[image: status field]

EDIT: Something like df['status:text']. Status has fields like 'text', 'created_at'. One option could be flattening/normalizing this json field like [this pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4007) Wes McKinney was working on.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you actually want to do?  You showed the `df['status']` column, but what do you want to do with it?

Comment: FWIW There's a PR in the works for this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4007

Comment: Are there nested records in the elements of `df.status`?

Comment: @BrenBarn - I was hoping to be able to select within those fields, somewhat like df[df['status']['favorited'] == False].

Comment: @PhillipCloud - Good to see that PR! Additionally, looks like someone else was doing the same type of thing with the Twitter API in this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1067.

Comment: I should note that I recognize that I can hack around this with a list comprehension, accessing the dictionary elements directly.

Comment: Should be a much neater way to read from mongo, creating python objects is not very efficient, and it's *basically* json... I created this issue a while back https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4329

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One solution is just to smash it with the Series constructor:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, {'a': 2}], [2, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   0                   1
0  1           {u'a': 2}
1  2  {u'a': 1, u'b': 3}

In [3]: df[1].apply(pd.Series)
Out[3]: 
   a   b
0  2 NaN
1  1   3
```

In some cases you'll want to [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html) this to the DataFrame in place of the dict row:

```
In [4]: dict_col = df.pop(1)  # here 1 is the column name

In [5]: pd.concat([df, dict_col.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
Out[5]: 
   0  a   b
0  1  2 NaN
1  2  1   3
```

*If the it goes deeper, you can do this a few times...*

Comment: Rad. This worked well, so long as there weren't null entries.

Comment: Also needed to merge the statuses in, adding a suffix so name collisions got decent names.

df2 = df[df.status.notnull()]
statuses = df2.status.apply(pandas.Series)
df2 = df2.merge(statuses, left_index=True, right_index=True,suffixes=("","_status"))

Comment: dang, that's annoying you have to special case NaN, another solution for that part is to fillna({}) first.

Comment: Oh that would have worked too, but I didn't need the empty results in this case.