# Pandas KeyError: “['value'] not in index”

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm having some issues with the index from a Pandas data frame. What I'm trying to do is load data from a JSON file, create a Pandas data frame and then select specific fields from that data frame and send it to my database.

The following is a link to what's in the JSON file so you can see the fields actually exist:
https://pastebin.com/Bzatkg4L

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Open and read the text file where all the Tweets are
with open('US_tweets.json') as f:
    tweets = f.readlines()

# Convert the list of Tweets into a structured dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(tweets)
# Attributes needed should be here
df = df[['created_at', 'screen_name', 'id', 'country_code', 'full_name', 'lang', 'text']]

# To create connection and write table into MySQL
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}"
                       .format(user="blah",
                               pw="blah",
                               db="blah"))

df.to_sql(con=engine, name='US_tweets_Table', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your original dataframe being constructed correctly? Specifically, what columns are present in that dataframe?

Comment: @Evan I think you might be right, how would I create columns for the dataframe? Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems as if you're saying I should create columns in the dataframe that associate with the attributes in the JSON file. And once those columns are made, I can add the attributes into the columns?

Comment: The error occurs because the columns you are trying to reference are not in the index: that is, they are not present in the first df you create. They are present within objects in the JSON file, but pandas does not create a column for every object in the JSON, just for the highest level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas doesn't map every object in the JSON file to a column in the dataframe. Your example file contains 24 columns:

```
with open('tweets.json') as f:
    df = pd.read_json(f, lines = True)
df.columns
```

Returns:

```
Index(['contributors', 'coordinates', 'created_at', 'entities',
   'favorite_count', 'favorited', 'geo', 'id', 'id_str',
   'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'in_reply_to_status_id',
   'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'in_reply_to_user_id',
   'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'is_quote_status', 'lang', 'metadata',
   'place', 'retweet_count', 'retweeted', 'source', 'text', 'truncated',
   'user'],
  dtype='object')
```

To dig deeper into the JSON data, I found this solution, but I hope a more elegant approach exists: [How do I access embedded json objects in a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665284/how-do-i-access-embedded-json-objects-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

For example, `df['entities'].apply(pd.Series)['urls'].apply(pd.Series)[0].apply(pd.Series)['indices'][0][0]`
returns `117`.

To access `full_name` and copy it to the df, try this:
    `df['full_name'] = df['place'].apply(pd.Series)['full_name']`, which returns `0    Austin, TX`.

Comment: Hey Evan, you've given a really good solution however when I try to access other attributes such as 'text' and 'id' in the same manner, I get an error. And why did you apply df['place'] to the 'full_name'? I tried it without 'place' and it gave the same error I had with accessing the other attributes.

Comment: **UPDATE** Ok the following attributes can easily be accessed via `print(df['attribute_here'])`: text, created_at, id and lang. It's only the **screen_name** and **country_code** that's empty.

Comment: **UPDATE 2** Ok so I figured out how to print **screen_name**, i didn't understand why you added 'place' for 'full_name' to work until I looked into the JSON file. The attribute 'user' contained 'screen_name' and that's why it worked. Great, I'll do my best to import the database now. Thanks Evan!

Comment: Glad you figured it out - I am not very familiar with JSON, so this was a nice learning opportunity for me, as well.